# Keyboard shortcuts for viewing the previous/next image

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm building a free (FOSS) image viewing application and would like for the user to be able to control both the panning of the image as well as changing to the previous or next image via the keyboard (for ease of use)

By default the graphical framework that I'm working with (Qt) uses left, right, up and down arrows as well as page up/down *for panning*, and I'd like to keep these as they are

However I'd also like to make it easy for the user to *go to the next and previous image*. **What keys or key combinations can you recommend? Is there a standard that can be followed?**

So far I've thought of using the N and P keys, or the ctrl or alt key modifier together with the left and right arrows

Grateful for help with this!
Tord

Comment: Which definition of *FOSS* are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i've updated the question to make it clear that i'm thinking of free software

Answer (score 1):

I've used multiple game console emulators that use Z and X buttons in the keyboard. Maybe that can be your Prev / Next. Their physical proximity is much easier to use than N and P.

Most first person shooting video games also use A and D to move left and right and W and S to move up and down.

http://support.neveralonegame.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200938319/PCControl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `ctrl-left` and `ctrl-right` to move to the left and right edges of the current image (somewhat like `ctrl-home` and `ctrl-end`), so I would suggest using `alt` combinations for moving to the previous (`alt-left`) or next (`alt-right`) images.